# woocommerce products category order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a template and I'm using the code to show the product categories on a page:

```
<?php $wcatTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC',  'parent' =>0)); //, 'exclude' => '17,77'
                foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
                    $wthumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $wcatTerm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                    $wimage = wp_get_attachment_url( $wthumbnail_id );
```

When I change the order in the backend it won't change.

How can I hard-code the order or set it to order by id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused `orderby` with `order`, they're 2 different arguments (see [`get_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)):

```
$wcatTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array(
    'hide_empty' => 0, 
    'orderby'    => 'id',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'parent'     => 0
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you do not have to hardcode anything.

1- Just go under Appearance->Widgets 
2- Under sidebar you added Woocommerce Product Categories expand "Woocommerce Product Categories"
3- At Order By dropdown box choose "Category Order" instead of name.

it should work now.

Comment: Clean and short answer.